# Question about Product Topology Basis

Tags: general-topology

I don't understand a comment in my topology lecture notes, but first let start with a

Definition Cartesian Product

For arbitrary set I the cartesian product is defined as

$\prod\limits_{i \in I}X_i :=${$x:I \rightarrow \bigcup_{i \in I}X_i| \forall i \in I:x(i) \in X_i $}

Furthermore $\pi_j$ is the projection defined as

$\pi_j$: $\prod\limits_{i \in I}X_i \rightarrow X_j$
with $\pi_j(x):=x(j)$

Definition of Product Topology
Let I be a non empty Set and let $X_i$ be a topological space for every $i \in I$, then the Set

$\mathcal{B}:=${$\prod\limits_{i \in I}U_i|\exists J \subseteq I$ finite$: U_i$ is open in $X_i$ for $i \in J$ and $U_i=X_i$ for $i \notin J$}

statisfies the properties of a basis.

Comment:
Obviously one can also take the set $U_i$ for $i \in J$
from a given base for $X_i$.

It is easy to see that $\mathcal{B}$ can be written as
$\mathcal{B}=${$\bigcap_{j \in J} \pi^{-1}(U_j)| J \subseteq I, J$ finite,$U_j$ open in $X_j $}

Especially $\mathcal{S}$:={$\pi^{-1}_i(U_i)|U_i$ open in $X_i$} is a Subbasis for the product topology.

What I don't understand is, why can $\mathcal{B}$ be written this way.  It would be nice if someone could explain it to me.

Edit:
I was a little bit unclear, I mean why does this equality hold

$\mathcal{B}:=${$\prod\limits_{i \in I}U_i|\exists J \subseteq I$ finite$: U_i$ is open in $X_i$ for $i \in J$ and $U_i=X_i$ for $i \notin J$}$=${$\bigcap_{j \in J} \pi^{-1}(U_j)| J \subseteq I, J$ finite,$U_j$ open in $X_j $}

Comment: Actually, it is $\bigcap_j \pi_j^{-1}(U_j),$ not $\bigcup.$

Comment: The product topology is the smallest topology such that each $\pi_i$ is continuous

Comment: @ThomasAndrews thank you I edited it

Comment: In words, things are open in the product topology if they are the product of finitely many open sets and all the other coordinates are the entire space for that coordinate.  If we allowed arbitrary products of any open sets, that is called the Box topology, and it fails to preserve a lot of continuity we'd want

Comment: Yes, the nice advantage of this “smallest topology” property is if $f_i:X\to X_i$ is a collection of continuous maps, then $f:X\to \prod_i X_i$ defined in the usual way is also continuous. Any larger topology on $\prod_i X_i$ would no longer satisfy this condition for all $X$ and $(f_i)_{i\in I}.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A general element in $\mathcal{B}$ has the form $A=\prod\limits_{i\in I} U_i$ where $U_i$ is open in $X_i$ and $U_i=X_i$ for all $i\notin J$ where $J\subseteq I$ is some finite set. Note that this element is exactly equal to $\bigcap\limits_{j\in J}\pi_j^{-1}(U_j)$. Just show a two sided inclusion. If $x\in A$ then for each $j\in J$ we have $\pi_j(x)\in U_j$ and so $x\in\pi_j^{-1}(U_j)$. Conversely, suppose that $x\in\bigcap\limits_{j\in J}\pi_j^{-1}(U_j)$. This means that for each $j\in J$ we have $\pi_j(x)\in U_j$. And since $U_i=X_i$ for all $i\notin J$ it trivially follows that also $\pi_i(x)\in U_i$ for all $i\notin J$. So we have $x(i)=\pi_i(x)\in U_i$ for all $i\in I$, and this means $x\in A$.

Comment: Why is $\pi_j(x) \in U_j$. From the definition I can only see that $\pi_j(x) \in X_j$

Comment: If $x\in A=\prod\limits_{i\in I}U_i$ then it means that $\pi_i(x)=x(i)\in U_i$ for all $i\in I$. It's just like with finite cartesian products, not any different. If $x=(x_1, x_2)\in A\times B$ then the first coordinate of $x$ belongs to $A$ and the second coordinate to $B$.

Comment: I think I got it now. Thanks